# Explore style element in GWT client code

Tags: html, css, gwt

I have a GWT code that creates a list (grid as result) and I set the style to a CSS class like

```
.test tr {
    height: 26px; 
}
```

now...if from code I need to obtain that "26px" when the render isn't completed or when the grid has no element? ho can I obtain that value? I know i can do

```
obj.getElement().getStyle().getProperty("height");
```

to obtain some style attribute but how can I obtain the sub-element tr related value?

Comment: Why do you need that? It looks like you are trying to solve a problem that may have an easier solution.

Comment: I need to calculate the number of visible rows in the component, i know that row could be bigger but i need at least to know the minimum forecastable size to calculate a reference value dependent from css settings (out of my control)

Comment: Why not take the "real" height of a row and/or the entire table, and then adjust accordingly? For example, you can render a table, get its height, adjust the number of rows - or whatever you need to adjust, then make it visible.

Comment: because the size is used to forecast the amount of data to retrieve and know it when the render is done means too late to do any consideration, data are already loaded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, the element's `style` property only contains styles that are directly set on the element itself - it does not automatically pick up css that has applied to it, or css that has been applied to parent nodes and inherited to it, etc.

To do this, you need to get the 'computed' style of the element. This is a somewhat expensive operation so should be done carefully, and will not work in older versions of IE, so different code entirely must be written. Some libraries like GXT have a built-in feature to do this work for you (`XElement.getComputedStyle(...)`), if you are not using a library like that, you will need to write JSNI that can call into this api and ask for these details.

Check out http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle (IE8 and below do not have it, old Android Browser and Opera Mini apparently have issues), and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle for the details on the call. In your JSNI, remember to use `$wnd` to refer to the `window` object, something like this:

```
    $wnd.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('height');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get that value programmatically. I imagine that you have only one or two styles that define your tables, so you can always infer the row height from your style name. For example, if you have "standard" height set at 26px and have a "big-table" style setting it at 36px, you can simply:

```
int rowHeight = myTable.getStyleName().contains("big-table") ? 36 : 26;
```

Comment: wrong assumption, the style is something that consumers of my war can change without my control, they can put any value, this isn't the answer to the question, it's a way to avoid the question!

Comment: First of all, I was trying to help, so I suggest that you change your attitude. Second, you never mention in your question that you have no control over a CSS file. This is a very unusual situation that can lead to a lot of problems.

Comment: Please Andrei, don't take me wrong, i'm grateful for any help and your time is appreciated, sorry if you had a different feeling. anyway going back to the core i think it's instead a really common condition: you realise a component or a portal that you customer will manage and, to integrate in other portals or just to adapt on graphic restylings, they change css...is something i passed lot of time, when you leave the product to the customer you never know what he will do! So far the Colin answer (that i still didn't try because a bit complex) seems the only possible

Comment: OK :) I think you are over-optimizing it a bit. If you are talking about a DataGrid, you can use a standard pagination approach that most apps use - load 10/20/50 records regardless of how many fit into a visible part.